# ClickOnce Hello World not working

Tags: deployment, clickonce

I read some documentation about how to do ClickOnce deployment and now I'm trying to deploy a hello world application.

I have a WPF default application (just an empty window).

This is what I do:

- Open project properties.
- Open publish wizard.
- Select a local server. I created a website using Visual Studio (File/New/WebSite) and then I can select it from the list. I used the one named **Test1**.

[image: local server]

- Then select the option that says *The application will be available online and offline*
- Publish
- Now I run the ISS Express server and go to `http://localhost:6507/publish.htm` that look like this:

[image: publish page]

- I hit the publish button and download **setup.exe**.
- But when I start **setup.exe** I get the following error:

[image: error msg]

- And the log is:

  ```
  The following properties have been set:
  Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
  Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
  Property: [NTProductType] = 1 {int}
  Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
  Property: [VersionNT] = 6.2.0 {version}
  Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
  Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework    Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
  Read string value '4.5.50938'
  Setting value '4.5.50938 {string}' for property 'DotNet45Full_TargetVersion'
  The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)':
  Property: [DotNet45Full_TargetVersion] = 4.5.50938 {string}
  Running checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe'
  Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
  Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
  Running checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe'
  Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
  Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'DotNet45Full_TargetVersion' and value '4.5.50709': true
  Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe' is 'Bypass'
  'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
  Launching Application.
  URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697208'
  Error: An error occurred trying to download     `http://agarwaen-pc:6507/WpfApplication1.application`.
  ```

I'm stuck with this because its a Hello World example and is not working. I need to deploy a project that is far more complex.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**PD: I'm thinking that the reason of the error may be the server that I'm using. I mean that I just point to a project that has the publish page and then right click *Show in browser* to start the ISS server. Maybe the setup program cannot download the required files because the server isn't serving those.**

**EDIT:**
I moved to not Express version of ISS and the **setup.exe** file now downloads successfully. Now I get another download error when the application is trying to download the remaining files. The message says **No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**

The message is:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.2.9200.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.18408
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://agarwaen-pc/WpfApplication1.application
                        Server      : Microsoft-IIS/8.0
    Deployment Provider url     : http://agarwaen-pc:6507/WpfApplication1.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://agarwaen-pc/WpfApplication1.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading http://agarwaen-pc:6507/WpfApplication1.application did not succeed.
        + Unable to connect to the remote server
        + No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 10.6.53.219:6507

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [4/25/2014 12:15:27 AM] : Activation of http://agarwaen-pc/WpfApplication1.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [4/25/2014 12:15:33 AM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading http://agarwaen-pc:6507/WpfApplication1.application did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifest(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ManifestType manifestType, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirect(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.FollowDeploymentProviderUri(SubscriptionStore subStore, AssemblyManifest& deployment, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Unable to connect to the remote server
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
        - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 10.6.53.219:6507
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
            at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: Bring up Fiddler. Looks like `http://mypcname:6507/WpfApplication1.application` does not equal `http://localhost:6507/WpfApplication1.application`.

Comment: @Aron the real message says: `http://agarwaen-pc:6507/WpfApplication1.application` and `agarwaen-pc` is the name of my pc. I will fix that to avoid confusions. sorry.

Comment: I realised that. But...if you are using virtual hosting with IIS, they are not the same. Additionally IIS Express does not allow you to access it with any address except `localhost`. Point your browser at that address and see if it downloads something.

Comment: @Aron That must be the error. When I point to `http://agarwaen-pc:6507/WpfApplication1.application` in browser I get `Bad Request`. Do I have to use IIS (not Express)?

Comment: IIS Express is designed with some flaws to prevent you from using it in production. In this case the `localhost` flaw, will stop you from using it off box, and you would need to rewrite everything (manually) in your deployment scripts to use `localhost`. Better to just switch to IIS proper.

Comment: @Aron Thanks. I'll try using IIS that comes with Windows 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a general issue with ClickOnce deployment. You **CANNOT** publish a ClickOnce app to your localhost and download it from there. I think the issue is about some internal Windows DNS/name resolving, which converts `localhost` to `your-pc:1234` - *always*. I had the same issue a few months ago, as I tried to publish my app to localhost. There's by now no workaround that I found. Locally, you would need to deploy as an offline package. You can use the online deployment (update from `http://...`) only with a server that is actually online. Nevertheless, you might try to use a UNC path (like `\\ServerInNetwork\Deployment\`) for testing the update process.
The update behavior between UNC and Web is the same.

Another [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223644/2132796) that may help you.

Comment: Thanks. It's really good to know the reason of those errors. (+1)