# Web server localhost could not be found error, when I try to publish with ClickOnce on localhost in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, localhost, clickonce

Web server localhost could not be found error, when I try to publish with ClickOnce on localhost in Visual Studio 2012.

These are my publish options:

[image]

And the error I get is this:

[image]

Comment: do you have IIS installed?

Comment: How can I check that? There is IIS Express folder in C:/Program Files if that is what you mean.

Comment: IIS is a feature of windows. In win8 you go to 'Add/Remove Programs' and click 'Turn Windows features on or off'. However it looks like you're using express instead. I've never tried to do that but I'm guessing you'd need to add the port number IIS Express is using - localhost:[PortNumber]. What do you want to accomplish by publishing a ClickOnce app to your local system?

Comment: I will eventually publish my app on a web, so that the user can install it from web site directly. At this point, I want to test with localhost only. But I want to simulate the whole scenario, and see how installation would go if I publish to localhost.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer about publishing to localhost [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23285803/2132796). This WON'T solve your problem, that `localhost` is not available, **BUT** it's a hint for your next step, where you **will** fail.