# What is the best way to publish a WPF application to Localhost using ClickOnce publishing tool

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I tried publishing a WPF application using my own Localhost as a server. But whenever I try publishing it, it says that the application was unable to find the end point web page used to display the installation instructions. 
I read somewhere that there is no way to publish to a Localhost using ClickOnce. Is it true? Or is there any other way to work around this?

Comment: Can you show us the exact error message that occurs?

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787154/clickonce-not-obeying-installation-folder-for-localhost - does it help?

Comment: What are your settings in Project properties -> Publish?

Comment: I was able to publish it to publish\ folder in my project folder itself. But when I place the published folder in server and try to download and execute it, I was getting the following error message:   - Downloading file:///C:/Users/Raghava/Downloads/Sample.UI.application did not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to copy the published files to any server and use them by downloading from there.
I opened up Command Prompt, navigated to the local path where the application is published and changed the URL of the setup.exe to the server in which we are going to place them.
For example: My application was published into C:\inetpub\wwwroot. So using Command prompt (better with administrative privileges) I navigated to 
c:\cd c:\inetpub\wwwroot
c:\inetpub\wwwroot>setup.exe /URL=http://servername/test
After successful execution, we can copy all the files from C:\inetpub\wwwrooot into the servername/test folder in server and can browse the server to download and install the application from anywhere with authentication.