# How to set proxy settings for IIS processes?

Tags: iis, proxy, iis-7.5

I have internet connection via http proxy, and some of my web applications at localhost need to access internet. Where can i set up proxy settings for them?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

All I needed was to set `system.net` in `web.config`

```xml
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy
        proxyaddress="http://10.0.2.231:42"
        bypassonlocal="true"
      />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

See:  [Element (Network Settings)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/defaultproxy-element-network-settings).

Comment: how about password and username for proxy? shouldn't we provide  that?

Comment: @BlueClouds as far as I know, there is no possibility to configure username and password from the web.config. The only possibility will be to use attribute **useDefaultCredentials=true**, in order to pass host credentials to the proxy.

Comment: @BlueClouds check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/8180854/1837339 and you probably need add the credentials through credential manager too https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/adding-credentials-to-windows-proxy-settings/d6fdab82-6163-4aad-8133-43f7706ceb9c