# Capture TFS API request running on IIS with Fiddler

Tags: c#, .net, iis, tfs, fiddler

I have web application that uses TFS API. The application is deployed on IIS. I have a need to profile requests to TFS by the app. After I installed Fiddler on my machine it started capturing all requests but request I really need.

Please, help!

Note: IIS 7.5, Windows 7 Ultimate, TFS 2013 (external one, being accessed through internet), .Net Framework 4.0 (App Pool), 4.5 (app code).

Comment: Actually I tried this technique and it didn't help. I used steps from this guide: http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-01-08/capturing-traffic-from-.net-services-with-fiddler

Comment: I've combined advice from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739669/how-to-set-proxy-settings-for-iis-processes and here http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-01-08/capturing-traffic-from-.net-services-with-fiddler and got it working. Thanks.