# Unable to connect to remote server using SoapHttpClientProtocol

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, soaphttpclientprotocol

The client has provided me with their location to .net asmx webservice. I created a library which I use in my web application to communicate with their web service.

In my library, I created a web reference to the asmx

This is my code to invoke their service

```cs
using (vendorproxy.vendorproxy wsProxy = new vendorproxy.vendorproxy())
{
    wsProxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(uname, pwd);

    using (Stream xmlStream = xmlUtil.GenerateStreamFromString(
        wsProxy.GetData(index)))
    {
        //
    }
}

public Stream GenerateStreamFromString(String inputString)
{
    byte[] bytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString);
    MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
    strm.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return strm;
}
```

The client developed a test app to test their service and it works. However my application when deployed on their system fails. I cannot step through the code as the client has not exposed the service outside of their network. This was developed by them providing sample output via xml file and their wsdl only.

The exception details:

```cs
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)     
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()     
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(
   String methodName, Object[] parameters)
```

App.config of my class library that has the web ref to the service and one that does the invoking. The class library is used by my web app

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="clientService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings />
        <client />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <applicationSettings>
        <clientService.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="clientService_client_client" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://localhost:2362/client.asmx</value>
            </setting>
        </clientService.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Solved:
This worked after i modified my original code from

```cs
using (vendorproxy.vendorproxy wsProxy = new vendorproxy.vendorproxy())
{
    wsProxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(uname, pwd);
}
```

TO

```cs
using (vendorproxy.vendorproxy wsProxy = new vendorproxy.vendorproxy())
{
    wsProxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(uname, pwd);
    wsProxy.URL = [correct asmx location read from config file]
    //not sure why it would not automatically pick up from config file. 
}
```

Comment: Can you ping the address at which the service is located from the server where the calling application is deployed?

Comment: A full exception message would be nice. You only provided a partial stack trace.

Comment: Service is located on http://machinename/somewhere/clientservice/somemthing.asmx, names changed and may not match above.  ping machinename works. no issues

Comment: @Tony Abrams: working on wiring up the entire exception.

Comment: I strongly urge you to try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8180854/98422) to a similar question. No code changes, just a line in your app.config file.

Answer (score 1):

You may be having problems with your proxy getting to an external address you may need to add something like this to your config.

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy
          autoDetect = "true" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Regards

Comment: @lain: My web app uses a class library, which connects to the webservice project. And this is my app.config from the class library that has a web ref to the service

Answer (score 0):

**My best guess (based off the limited exception information):**

You should be updating the location used to connect to the webservice when you deploy it on their server(s).

The location is usually a URI/URL inside of the web.config or app.config.

Comment: When deployed on thier system. I updated my library.dll.config to point to where the asmx is located too.

Comment: Also, I have never been able to access their system as they have note xpposed it out of their network. Only developed it using a wsdl and an xml file that represents data being sent by their service

Comment: Do you have the URI/URL they use in their test application?

Comment: Yeah I just realized the 'cannot access outside their network part'  I removed that from my answer.

Comment: The url they have their service exposed in their test machine on their network is http://machinename/somewhere/clientservice/somemthing.asmx. When i RDP on their machine, i can open IE and hit that url

Comment: This is going to be hard to answer without the full exception.

Comment: Will put it up in 1.5hrs as the clients are not in yet at work.