# Newtonsoft JSON Schema - $ref is not resolved, getting authentication error for url

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema

I am trying to use $ref from URL & validating json data using NewtonSoft.Json.Schema.

1. MainSchema.json

   ```
   {
       "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
       "type": "object",
       "properties": {
           "Data": { "$ref": "http://localhost:49735/api/schema/sample" },
       },
       "required": [ "Data" ]
   }
   ```
2. SubSchema.json

   ```
   {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
       "type": "object",
       "properties": 
       {
           "Data": 
           {
               "type": "array",
               "items": 
               [
                   {
                       "type": "array",
                       "items": 
                       [
                           {
                               "id": "id1",
                               "type": "string",
                           },
                           {
                               "id": "id2",
                               "type": "number"
                           }
                       ]
                   }
               ]
           }
       }
   }
   ```

I have created one sample web api application for downloading subschema as json.
URL is reffered in main schema http://localhost:49735/api/Schema/Sample
The api is developed with No Authentication Mode.
I am using NewtonSoft JSON Schema for validation json data. but while resolving json schema it is throwing exception.

```
"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
```

Comment: Try to copy the $ref uri into the browser a test the response with the network tool in the web developer tools. Or use `curl`. If there is a 401 response, the error is in your server configuration.

Comment: from browser it works without any issue. seems like it is just because is unable to use n/w proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a proxy issue on your local network. You could try configuring .NET to use your computer's configured proxy - [How to authenticate against a proxy when using the HttpClient class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827976/how-to-authenticate-against-a-proxy-when-using-the-httpclient-class)

Comment: It was the issue only. I used proxy & it solved my issue. Thanks James.