# Facebook SDK Proxy setting C#

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I use Facebook SDK .net but I use proxy with authentication to connect to the internet 
I get the error (407) (407) proxy authentication required how I can set the authentication on Facebook SDK

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a static method in FacebookClient which allows you to set it globally.

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public static void SetDefaultHttpWebRequestFactory(Func<Uri, HttpWebRequestWrapper> httpWebRequestFactory)
```

You might not see it in the intellisense as it is hidden by default.

If you want it per instance you can use the property.

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public virtual Func<Uri, HttpWebRequestWrapper> HttpWebRequestFactory { get; set; }
```

Here is an example.

```
FacebookClient.SetDefaultHttpWebRequestFactory(uri => {
    var request = new HttpWebRequestWrapper((HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri));
    request.Proxy = ......; // normal .net IWebProxy
    return request;
});
```

Comment: I can't get it, there is no    acebookClient.SetDefaultHttpWebRequestFactory                          my code is C# code

Comment: it is static not instance FacebookClient.SetDefaultHttpWebRequestFactory. It is hidden from intellisense so you might not see it. check the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue when using `FacebookClient` to post to a Facebook page. In my case I have a WCF service that is responsible for the Facebook interactions and the service sits behind a company proxy. [This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8180854/132599) resolved the issue for me but requires the IIS app pool user identity for the service to be set to a user that has domain credentials, otherwise the 407 error is returned. So set the app pool identity to a domain account and add the following to web.config:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```