# Facebook permission error

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // The application key of the Facebook application used
            fbService.ApplicationKey = "XXXXXXXXXXX";

            // Add all needed permissions
            List<Enums.ExtendedPermissions> perms = new List<Enums.ExtendedPermissions>
            {
               Enums.ExtendedPermissions.none
        };
            fbService.ConnectToFacebook(perms);   //error here (The given key was not present in the dictionary.)         
        }
```

I mention the error where I get the error , as am new to facebook api and specially new to c# any explained answer is appriciated
Thank you

Comment: Are you using the Facebook C# SDK? This code doesn't look familiar.

Answer (score 0):

Use the static method on FacebookClient like this:

```
FacebookClient.SetDefaultHttpWebRequestFactory(uri => {
    var request = new HttpWebRequestWrapper((HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri));
    request.Proxy = ......; // normal .net IWebProxy
    return request;
});
```

See this answer also: [Facebook SDK Proxy setting C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251150/facebook-sdk-proxy-setting-c-sharp)