# How to set VB Application Proxy Settings to Default System Proxy Settings

Tags: vb.net, proxy, ip

My application is supposed to work on a Company Network where proxy is enabled,
By default when logged in all applications like browser and all can access internet normally

But when i open my application "The remote server returned an error [407] Proxy Authentication Required" error is coming

In normal internet connected PC it works well

Is there any way to set manual proxy or more preferably set the system proxy as default to the application
I am too novice in the programming field

My code is

```
Dim PartURL As String = "http://www.google.com"
Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(PartURL)
Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
Dim sourcecode As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
SearchPageSource = sourcecode
```

Also my proxy settings is

```
Address: abcserver04
Port:    8080
```

Ipconfig output on cmd prompt is

```
Ethernet adapter local area connection
Connection Specific DNS Suffix : abc.defgroup.net
IP Address : 10.4.8.xx
Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway : 10.4.8.254
```

Comment: The very fact you're getting that error suggests it IS using the proxy. You just need to pass the correct credentials through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `app.config`.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/8180854/239408

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```