# Proxy setting for all app connection

Tags: c#, proxy

Is there any default proxy setup for all outgoing connection for a C# application?

I am developing a small program that use third party C# libraries. there are two libraries from different vendors. Both take data from Internet. My program should connect trough a proxy, but the server shouldn't.

I need to set a proxy for the program only. I try to use `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy`. For one DLL it works, but for another one it doesn't. The working DLL uses the 443 port, the non-working DLL uses custom ports.

Is there any option to set proxies for C# applications?

Comment: "second uses custom ports" are you sure it is even using HTTP at all?

Comment: got any firewalls ? for example, where I work, port 80 and 443 would work through the proxy, but non standard ports dont.

Comment: I suppose it is not HTTP, it is probably Sockets. Can I use DefaultProxy with other protocols, or can I use something like  DefaultProxy with other protocols? The second dll still connect to remote resourse, but ignore WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy. First one connect through proxy. For now proxy open for all ports.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19086729/2401021):

> This will force the DefaultWebProxy to use default credentials,
>   similar effect as done through UseDefaultCredentials = true.
>
> Hence all newly created WebRequest instances will use default proxy
>   which has been configured to use proxy's default credentials.

Of course you could be experiencing another issue i.e. the none default port is being blocked by the proxy or a firewall. You could try a telnet to verify that the port is accessible.

Comment: Any particular reason why OP should "try this"?