# Are there drawbacks to using WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials when there is no proxy?

Tags: c#, .net, security, http, proxy

I have a situation where a user running my .NET application may be behind a proxy.

I have found that using

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

at the beginning of the program always allows requests to work, whether or not a proxy is specified in the operating system Local Area Network (LAN) Settings dialog for example.

Without this line, when behind a proxy I get a 407 Proxy Authentication Required when making a request.

Is there any downside to always executing this line in my program? In most cases users do not go through a proxy, so is there significant additional overhead for example, either in code or over the wire, or any other disadvantages in using this when a proxy isn't present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iwebproxy.credentials(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Credentials property is an ICredentials instance that contains the authorization credentials to send to the proxy server **in response to an HTTP 407 (proxy authorization) status code**.

As only users behind a proxy will ever receive a 407, other users will not be affected.

Comment: See also [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299940/how-should-i-set-the-default-proxy-to-use-default-credentials/8180854#comment11286255_8180854)