# unable to know what is blocking to my application to communicate to Web service

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

Recently we were facing an issue in client place is that we were unable to communicate to web service even we checked that there is no system proxy set in that system, to overcome this we had given a dummy proxy (localhost:port) and its started working well but after some days with dummy proxy it was unable to communicate to service if we remove dummy proxy then it started working well. i am not able to understand what is blocking me to communicate to service. what may be the issue and how can we overcome this problem. This issue is happening only on some system.

Actually it has to go and hit this URL [http://********-tech.in:8080/******dp/ClientVersion](http://*******-tech.in:8080/*******/ClientVersion) but suddenly it started hitting this one 125.21.244.38:8080 why i am not able to conclude.

```
2017-05-05 00:19:44,721 ERROR [Heartbeat Service             ] - Exception while sending heartbeat to manager.  
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 125.21.244.38:8080
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at HeartbeatWSImplService.heartbeat(String probeUid, heartbeatRequest heartbeatRequest)
   at ProHance.ProbeHeartBeat.HeartBeat.timer_Elapsed(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read this post here they are telling to set the default proxy for the webservice request, they are trying to the proxy details while connecting to google. If there is no proxy configured you can try the method mentioned there. [Set the default proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299940/how-should-i-set-the-default-proxy-to-use-default-credentials).